# Eric IDE: How do I change the shell from python3 to python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, python-3.x, ide

Hey I'm just starting out with Eric6. Is it possible to change the shell to use python 2.* instead of python3? can't find anything related to that in the preferences?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple and safe way is using `alias`. To change to python2, you can use the following command:

```
alias python=python2
```

This will change the default version to Python2.
To revert back:

```
alias python=python3
```

Add required line into your  ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases file.

Note, using `ln` could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `python2` interpreter is opened with the `python` command, and the `python3` interpreter is opened with the `python3` command. On linux, you may want to put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your code.